# Как передать и использовать props для однофайловых компонентов?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, компоненты

Есть однофайловый компонент `parkInfo.vue`, я пытаюсь передать с `main.js`, где регистрируется этот компонент, входной параметр `park`. 
**main.js** тут регистрирую компонент

```js
Vue.component(
    "popup",
    require("./vue-components/parkInfo.vue").default,
    {
        props: [ "park" ]
    });
```

**parkInfo.vue** сам этот компонент

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h1>...</h1>
            <h2>{{ park }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {{ ... }}
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
     ...
</script>
```

**home.blade.php** здесь использую этот компонент

```html
<div id="modal">
    <popup park="Какой то известный парк"></popup>
</div>
```

Выводится такая ошибка в консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*P.S. Если декларировать свойство `park` и оставить его, к примеру с пустым значением ("") как об этом говорится в документации, то vue будет использовать именно это значение, а не то, что было передано во входном параметре*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vue.component( id, [definition] )` принимает два аргумента (согласно [Vue API](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component))

Пример использования `props` в компоненте:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  props: {
    testvalue: {
      type: String,
      default: 'no string'
    },
  },
  template: `
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Компонент my-component</legend>
  props testvalue = <b>{{ testvalue }}</b>
</fieldset>
  `
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    valueforcomponent: 'Строковое значение для компонента'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component :testvalue="valueforcomponent"></my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: готов поклясться что видел в каком-то ответе на англоязычном со принятый ответ с такой формой записи :\

Comment: не буду отрицать) думаю, если вы перенесете ваш `props` в компонент `parkInfo.vue` - все будет работать